# Msg Dependencies in Catkin

Tags: ros, catkin, tutorial, turtlesim, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to writing packages in ROS and am confused about message dependencies in catkin.

If I'm going to use the turtlesim/Velocity.msg, what do I have to include in my CMakeLists.txt and my package.xml files? I am *not* writing my own msg - I simply want to publish turtlesim/Velocity messages to a topic.

In Section 1.3 in the [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial, it says you are supposed to add this to the CMakeLists.txt file:

> generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

When I did that tutorial, I was able to run my talker and listener without adding that line; in fact, when I DID add that line and ran catkin_make, I got an error saying

> Unknown CMake command "generate_messages"

Please let me know how I can fix my dependencies, and also if I should worry about "generate_messages" creating an error.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66566/msg-dependencies-in-catkin/) by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generate_messages is only needed when you define your own custom messages.

Assuming you are accessing messages defined in some other package using C++, this [how-to page](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/cpp_msg_dependencies.html) should help.

If you access the messages via Python, see [this page](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/python_module_dependencies.html), too.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on 2013-07-03**:
It says there to add the following:

add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(your_library ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

What exactly is "your_program" and "your_library", do they mean 'Package name' and 'Executable'?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-03**:
They stand for whichever of your build targets depend on the message headers. A C++ build target is usually either an executable or a library.

**Comment by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on 2013-07-03**:
Now I'm getting the error "Adding dependency to non-existent target: beginner_tutorials"

Am I supposed to be adding something else? I already included "target_link_libraries" the same way it is done for talker and listener in the tutorials.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-03**:
Apparently you have some dependency on beginner_tutorials, which is not being resolved. Can you `roscd beginner_tutorials`?

**Comment by [asriraman93](https://answers.ros.org/users/5035/asriraman93/) on 2013-07-03**:
if I do source ./devel/setup.bash, yes.

BUT, if I do "rosmsg package beginner_tutorials" nothing shows up - not even std_msgs/String

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-03**:
You HAVE TO source ./devel/setup.bash ;) After you do that, you should be able to catkinise your package.